# C# TextWriter writing weird characters

Tags: c#, streamwriter, memorystream, textwriter

I have a server that is writing some text files, but since the text in question has some specific latin characters, such as "á","ã" and "é" , the result turns out to be quite odd. `TextWriter` in C# supposedly writes with utf-8 encoding, so that shouldn't be a problem, right?

Here is how I'm using it:

```
System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
System.IO.StreamWriter textWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(stream);

textWriter.WriteLine("Número da Versão:");
textWriter.Flush();

byte[] contents = new byte[stream.Length];
stream.Read(contents, 0, (int)stream.Length);
```

The result for this line comes out as:

```
NÃºmero da versÃ£o:
```

Comment: The result is not text, but an array of bytes that represent the utf-8 encoding of the text, the problem lies in how you convert those bytes to text. What is your code for that?

Comment: `System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(contents)` produces the weird characters.  `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(contents)` produces the correct string: "Número da Versão:\r\n".  So I think that's your problem.  Also, to reproduce your problem, I had to set `stream.Position = 0` after the call to `Flush()`.

Comment: Well i'm using Microsoft SharePoint, i used the SPFileCollection.Add method with the (String, Stream) overload

Comment: [This post](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/28951/create-a-document-library-item-base-on-a-contenttype-with-javascript-object-mode) suggests you should use `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode` instead of `UTF8`.  Maybe give that a try?

Comment: `Encoding.Unicode` also suggested [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/230c4d32-ce18-4801-9d55-e0843255eedd/how-to-add-a-new-item-to-a-document-library-that-has-an-infopath-custom-form-through-client-object?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious).

Comment: Thank you, it worked using `new System.IO.StreamWriter(stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);`

Comment: I reproduce your write locally and it works just fine. So I think your mistake is in your byte to string conversion.